# Handle AngularJS errors while loading template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create an app with requirement of template files being in two folders - first is available without restrictions and second is available only for logged in users.

Things are complicating when somebody refresh the page and session expire before. Angular throws error (e.g. 401) in console while loading template file which I want to avoid. Is there a way to catch that event and access response status to for e.g. redirect the page?

Comment: so you want to redirect the page whenever there is an error?

Comment: Perfectly redirect or change location.hash will be one of the options, depends of the response status.

Comment: Have you thought about $http interceptors? you can define what to do whenever errors happen then redirect to an err page? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi - thank you, it is what I looked for.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, we can catch the error and redirect to a page with the help of `$location.url()`. Here is the concept. Now i have a controller and in that, i have success function and error function. Whenever we get an error, the error function will run and we can pass the link of the page you want to redirect.

```
$http.get(url,[params])
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    // bind your data to scope
      })
     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $location.url('/404');
      });
```

By the use of `$routeProvider`, you can configure the function something like
this :

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/404', {
       templateUrl: '404.html',
       controller: 'yourcontroller'
});
```

And you can see the [description](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for $location.url() here

Hope it works